# Select column from current table to a related table

Tags: mysql, join

I have this schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `players` (
    `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`)
);

CREATE TABLE `teams` (
    `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
    `player_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `message` text NOT NULL,
    `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

I need to query `teams` table, where `player_id` has email `barcelonafc@outlook.com`, and also sorting it by the last 30 days of creation in the database.

Right now I have this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM teams 
WHERE created_at BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND NOW();
```

This query is fine for selecting from `teams` and for filtering by the last 30 days of creation.

But, I can't figure out how to actually access `players` from it, and then filter by `email='barcelonafc@outlook.com'` as well.

I know it might be a dumb question, but, any ideas?

Should I change the schema for this?

It is a MySQL database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let’s join on `player_id`

```
SELECT * 
  FROM teams t INNER JOIN players p ON t.player_id = p.id
 WHERE t.created_at >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
   and p.email = 'barcelonafc@outlook.com'
```

Be sure to verify if the results should be filtered on *players* added within the last 30 days or *teams*.

Comment: Awesome dude, thanks